# Verifying Windows 8 inapp-purchase receipt signature in Python

Tags: python, xml, windows-8, in-app-purchase, xmlsec

I'm trying to validate Windows 8 receipt XML signature using pyxmlsec.

My receipt (`receipt.xml`) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><Receipt Version="1.0" ReceiptDate="2012-08-30T23:10:05Z" CertificateId="b809e47cd0110a4db043b3f73e83acd917fe1336" ReceiptDeviceId="4e362949-acc3-fe3a-e71b-89893eb4f528"><AppReceipt Id="8ffa256d-eca8-712a-7cf8-cbf5522df24b" AppId="55428GreenlakeApps.CurrentAppSimulatorEventTest_z7q3q7z11crfr" PurchaseDate="2012-06-04T23:07:24Z" LicenseType="Full" /><ProductReceipt Id="6bbf4366-6fb2-8be8-7947-92fd5f683530" ProductId="Product1" PurchaseDate="2012-08-30T23:08:52Z" ExpirationDate="2012-09-02T23:08:49Z" ProductType="Durable" AppId="55428GreenlakeApps.CurrentAppSimulatorEventTest_z7q3q7z11crfr" /><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" /><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /><DigestValue>cdiU06eD8X/w1aGCHeaGCG9w/kWZ8I099rw4mmPpvdU=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>SjRIxS/2r2P6ZdgaR9bwUSa6ZItYYFpKLJZrnAa3zkMylbiWjh9oZGGng2p6/gtBHC2dSTZlLbqnysJjl7mQp/A3wKaIkzjyRXv3kxoVaSV0pkqiPt04cIfFTP0JZkE5QD/vYxiWjeyGp1dThEM2RV811sRWvmEs/hHhVxb32e8xCLtpALYx3a9lW51zRJJN0eNdPAvNoiCJlnogAoTToUQLHs72I1dECnSbeNPXiG7klpy5boKKMCZfnVXXkneWvVFtAA1h2sB7ll40LEHO4oYN6VzD+uKd76QOgGmsu9iGVyRvvmMtahvtL1/pxoxsTRedhKq6zrzCfT8qfh3C1w==</SignatureValue></Signature></Receipt>
```

And here's my certificate (`cert`):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

And it does validates when I'm using `xmlsec1` console program (thanks to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912647/)):

```
$ xmlsec1 --verify --pubkey-cert-pem cert receipt.xml
OK
SignedInfo References (ok/all): 1/1
Manifests References (ok/all): 0/0
```

Now I'm trying to do the same using pyxmlsec package (and its [docs](http://pyxmlsec.labs.libre-entreprise.org/index.php?section=examples&id=6)):

```
In [1]: import xmlsec; xmlsec.init(); xmlsec.cryptoInit(); xmlsec.cryptoAppInit(None)
Out[1]: 0

In [2]: mngr = xmlsec.KeysMngr(); xmlsec.cryptoAppDefaultKeysMngrInit(mngr)
Out[2]: 0

In [3]: mngr.certLoad('cert', xmlsec.KeyDataFormatCertPem , xmlsec.KeyDataTypePublic)
Out[3]: 0

In [4]: dsig_ctx = xmlsec.DSigCtx(mngr)

In [5]: import libxml2; f = libxml2.parseFile('receipt.xml'); node = xmlsec.findNode(f.getRootElement(), xmlsec.NodeSignature, xmlsec.DSigNs)

In [6]: dsig_ctx.verify(node)
func=xmlSecKeysMngrGetKey:file=keys.c:line=1370:obj=unknown:subj=xmlSecKeysMngrFindKey:error=1:xmlsec library function failed: 
func=xmlSecDSigCtxProcessKeyInfoNode:file=xmldsig.c:line=871:obj=unknown:subj=unknown:error=45:key is not found: 
func=xmlSecDSigCtxProcessSignatureNode:file=xmldsig.c:line=565:obj=unknown:subj=xmlSecDSigCtxProcessKeyInfoNode:error=1:xmlsec library function failed: 
func=xmlSecDSigCtxVerify:file=xmldsig.c:line=366:obj=unknown:subj=xmlSecDSigCtxSigantureProcessNode:error=1:xmlsec library function failed: 
Out[6]: -1
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can it be fixed? Or is there any better python package for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that using `mngr.certLoad` on a certificate file returns 0, ie. success, when in fact the key manager does not hold any valid keys (bug?). I got the idea from these two lines, which imply that there is no key:

```
func=xmlSecKeysMngrGetKey:file=keys.c:line=1370:obj=unknown:subj=xmlSecKeysMngrFindKey:error=1:xmlsec library function failed: 
func=xmlSecDSigCtxProcessKeyInfoNode:file=xmldsig.c:line=871:obj=unknown:subj=unknown:error=45:key is not found:
```

The solution is to convert the certificate file into a public key file using openssl:

`openssl x509 -inform pem -in cert -pubkey -noout > pubkey`

Then, you can use this key to verify the signature with the python library:

```
>>> key = xmlsec.cryptoAppKeyLoad('pubkey', xmlsec.KeyDataFormatPem, None, None, None)
>>> dsig_ctx = xmlsec.DSigCtx()
>>> dsig_ctx.signKey = key
>>> dsig_ctx.verify(node)
0
>>> dsig_ctx.status == xmlsec.DSigStatusSucceeded
True
```

Or, same thing with a key manager:

```
>>> key = xmlsec.cryptoAppKeyLoad('pubkey', xmlsec.KeyDataFormatPem, None, None, None)
>>> mngr = xmlsec.KeysMngr(); xmlsec.cryptoAppDefaultKeysMngrInit(mngr)
0
>>> xmlsec.cryptoAppDefaultKeysMngrAdoptKey(mngr, key)
0
>>> dsig_ctx = xmlsec.DSigCtx(mngr)
>>> dsig_ctx.verify(node)
0
>>> dsig_ctx.status == xmlsec.DSigStatusSucceeded
True
```

I stumbled upon an old [email thread](http://www.aleksey.com/pipermail/xmlsec/2008/008446.html) in which a user of the xmlsec c library describes his trouble with using the certificate file directly, and gives the aforementioned command to convert it to a public key.

He is also able to get the library to perform the conversion [a few emails later](http://www.aleksey.com/pipermail/xmlsec/2008/008453.html) by making a call to `xmlSecOpenSSLAppKeyFromCertLoadBIO`. Presumably the xmlsec command line utility does this when given the `--pubkey-cert-pem` flag. However, I was not able to find a corresponding method in the python library after greping around for a bit. So it looks like at the moment it's not possible.

## Edit

It is possible to convert the certificate to a public key using [M2Crypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/M2Crypto) ([documentation](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/)), a Python wrapper for OpenSSL. I adapted answers from [Extracting public key from certificate...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5791806/3565972) and a blog post from [Sheogora](http://sheogora.blogspot.com/2012/03/m2crypto-for-python-x509-certificates.html) to work with this particular case.

```
>>> from M2Crypto import X509
>>> cert = X509.load_cert('cert', X509.FORMAT_PEM)
>>> pubkey = cert.get_pubkey().get_rsa()
>>> pubkey.save_key('pubkey', cipher=None)
1 # Success
```

The public key will be saved in PEM format with no encryption to file **pubkey** and can now be loaded using `xmlsec.cryptoAppKeyLoad('pubkey', xmlsec.KeyDataFormatPem, None, None, None)`.

Comment: It works fine, thank you! By the way, is there any way to make this conversion using pyOpenSSL (or some other) library?

Comment: @DrTyrsa See my edit. It is possible using M2Crypto. I was trying to avoid writing the public key to a file and then reading it again, but can't think of a way. Unfortunately, it appears that pyxmlsec only wants a file name as input.

Answer (score 2):

This is how the receipt can be validated without external files:

```
import xmlsec
from lxml import etree
from M2Crypto import X509
import StringIO
```

def validate_win_signature(receipt, cert):
    xml = etree.fromstring(receipt)
    xmlsec.tree.add_ids(xml, ["ID"])
    signature_node = xmlsec.tree.find_node(xml, xmlsec.Node.SIGNATURE)
    assert signature_node is not None
    assert signature_node.tag.endswith(xmlsec.Node.SIGNATURE)
    ctx = xmlsec.SignatureContext()
    certx509 = X509.load_cert_string(cert)
    pubkey = certx509.get_pubkey().get_rsa().as_pem(cipher=None)
    keystream = StringIO.StringIO(pubkey)
    key = xmlsec.Key.from_memory(keystream, xmlsec.KeyFormat.PEM)
    ctx.key = key
    ctx.verify(signature_node)